# In Vim, how to open Explorer in Current working directory?

Tags: vim

In windows, I want to open explorer.exe in the current working directory.

I've tried this one but doesn't work

`nnoremap <leader>e :!start explorer /select,getcwd()<CR>`

I derived it from this one that works (but opens current buffer file, which is not what I need)

`nnoremap <leader>f :!start explorer /select,%:p<CR>`

Comment: I heavily suspect `getcwd()` is not getting called in vim, but is passed to the shell as-is. Seems to be the case with `... :!echo getcwd()<CR>` on my machine.

Comment: @Michail I've been testing it, and that seems to be the case, as it keeps opening ~/My Documents for me, on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

`getcwd()` doesn't get expanded before being passed to the command interpreter.

A workaround, modified from the help for `:!` and `:exe`, would be the following:

`nnoremap <leader>e :execute "!start explorer /select," . shellescape(getcwd(),1)`

The result of the `getcwd()` function gets appended to the `!start` command before being passed to the shell/command interpreter, and the `shellescape()` function is used to escape any space or other special characters that may be in the path, although it shouldn't be an issue with Windows Explorer.

Comment: I don't know whether it's necessary for `cmd` and `explorer`, but usually it's reasonable to additionally `shellescape` the path, in case it has spaces or special characters.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be an issue with explorer, but I will add it to the answer.